# Microprocessor8086 masm debug wont show me the whole code

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am new to assembly coding.
When debugging, the option wont show me the whole code till HLT

```
ASSUME CS :CODE, DS :DATA

DATA SEGMENT
    NUM1 DB 1H, 1H
    NUM2 DB 1H, 1H
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
START:
    MOV BX, DATA
    MOV DS, BX
    MOV CL, 2H
    LEA SI, NUM1
    LEA DI, NUM2
LOOP1:
    ADD AL, [SI]
    MOV DL, AL
    ADD DL, 48
    ADD AX, [DI]
    INC DI
    MOV AH, 2H
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    DEC CL
    JNZ LOOP1

HLT
CODE ENDS
END START
```

In the given pic the debug option only shows me the code till DEC CL, but to execute the whole code
[image: assembly listing]
I need to get the HLT so that I can run it using the -g addr command.
Is there any alternative to this? or is my code wrong in some way?

Comment: Don't you just type `u` again to get the next page of assembly listing? (It's been years since I used debug)

Comment: omfg i had no idea that was a thing. tysm !!

Comment: You can use `u` or `u 20` to continue the disassembly.

Comment: You've chosen an incredibly primitive way to get started with assembly language - an architecture (16-bit x86) that hasn't been used for any new code in 20 years, an operating system that hasn't been used for as long, a debugger that hasn't advanced significantly since it was written over 40 years ago.  Are you deliberately into retrocomputing?  Otherwise, are you sure this is what you want to get into?

Comment: well.. our college uses this so I dont have any choice but to learn it.. the  same thing has happened with graphics course that I took. It uses graphics.h from c which is outdated but I got no other choice than to learn..

Comment: The most comfortable way I know of for debugging 16-bit DOS code is using TASM/TurboDebugger. It has a very nice textmode GUI. Give it a try, if you want to continue this way.

Comment: Going forward, I recall debug.exe was removed starting with with Windows 7. https://superuser.com/questions/510671/is-there-debug-exe-equivalent-for-windows7